# Spring Boot - Can't add inline image using thymeleaf mail template

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to add an inline image in thymeleaf email html template like in tutorials, but nothings work.

This is my method from service class:

```
public void sendOrderDetailsEmail(PortfolioModel model)  {  
        try {

          MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
          MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
          Context context = new Context();
          context.setVariable("portfolio", model);
          context.setVariable("products", model.getProducts());
          context.setVariable("logo", "logo");

          String htmlContent = templateEngine.process(ORDER_DETAILS_HTML, context);
          message.addInline("logo", new ClassPathResource("images/logo.png"), "image/png");

          LOG.info("Sending order configuration email to  " + model.getUser().email);
          configureMessage(message, model.getUser().email, "Order details", htmlContent);
          mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(e);
        }
    }

private void configureMessage(MimeMessageHelper message, String to, String subject, String content) 
{
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("myemail@address.org", "info"));
    message.setTo(to);
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setText(content, true /* is html */);
}
```

---

And this is my thymeleaf HTML template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>
    <img src="logo.png" th:src="|cid:${logo}|" />
</p>
<div th:object="${portfolio}">
    <p><span th:utext="${portfolio.user.fullname}"></span></p>
    <p><b>Your order id: </b><span th:utext="${portfolio.orderId}"></span></p>
    <p><b>Order information:</b></p>
   <div th:if="${products} != null">
       <table>
         <tr th:each="product : ${products}">
             - Product:
            <td th:text="${product.model}"></td >
            <td th:text="${product.year}"></td >
            <td th:text="${product.color}"></td >
        </tr>
       </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

All above the `<img src=...>` which is not appearing, works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your message as a Multipart message like this:

```
final MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED, "UTF-8"); // true = multipart
```

It is not sufficient to just set multipart to `true`.

Comment: Your answer helped in my case, I think this is the correct solution for this question.